# MergeSort() implementation returning the initial unsorted array

Tags: c#, mergesort

Every time I run this it returns an unsorted array. I've placed some code to signal me where things are and are not happening, but it LOOKS and SEEMS like everything works fine, yet it won't actually sort anything.

```
 public static int[] MergeSort(int[] array)
    {
        if(array.Length <= 1)
        {
            return array;
        }
        (int[], int[]) p = SplitArray(array);
        int[] left = MergeSort(p.Item1);
        int[] right = MergeSort(p.Item2);
        return Merge(left, right);


    }



    public static int[] Merge(int[] low, int[] high)
    {
        int[] middle = new int[(low.Length + high.Length + 1)];
        int count = 0;
        foreach (int item in low)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("low: " + item + ',');
        }
        foreach (int item in high)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("high: " + item + ',');
        }
        int low_index = 0;
        int high_index = 0;
        while (low_index < low.Length && high_index < high.Length)
        {
            if(low[low_index] < high[high_index])
            {
                middle.SetValue(low[low_index], count);
                low_index++;
                count++;
                Console.WriteLine("Low inserted.");
            }
            else
            {
                middle.SetValue(high[high_index], count);
                high_index++;
                count++;
                Console.WriteLine("High inserted.");
            }

        }
        if (low_index == low.Length)
        {
            high.CopyTo(middle, high_index);
        }
        else
        {
            low.CopyTo(middle, low_index);
        }

        return middle;
    }


    public static (int[], int[]) SplitArray(int[] k)
    {
        int MAXINDEX = k.Length - 1;
        int count = 0;
        int[] a = new int[(MAXINDEX / 2)];
        int[] b = new int[(MAXINDEX / 2)];

        for (int i = 0; i < (MAXINDEX / 2); i++)
        {
            a[i] = k[i];
        }
        for (int i = ((MAXINDEX / 2) + 1); i < MAXINDEX; i++)
        {
            b[count] = k[i];
            count++;

        }
        return (a, b);

    }
```

I have no idea where I am going wrong here. I might just be overlooking something from being very tired every time I come back to this. I basically print out a bunch of things that SHOULD be happening using the console and it all seems correct, and I am losing my mind.

Comment: Why not start with a small array and use the debugger to step through your code so you can see what's happening?

Comment: I've been doing that. I forgot to snip out the Console.WriteLine 's in my post, but i basically rran it through a bunch of randomly generated arrays which all LOOKED like the function was running the way I wanted it to, but it keeps giving me the initial array.

Comment: @MasonHanna Your `CopyTo` lines at the end of your `Merge()` method looks wrong. You are trying to copy the array which you already have added to the `middle` array. Or you start re-adding them to the beginning of the `middle` array.  It might be easier to use two normal `while` loops to copy the remaining numbers from one of the arrays.

Comment: @Progman Upon doing this, I've now noticed that there is something wonky with my Split function where some items get dropped during the split... according to what it's printing anyway. Either something gets dropped or right becomes an array of 0's when it shouldn't.

Comment: so with the help of everyone here, i not only determined what was wrong, but also figured out why my printed array was always the same one. I reprinted the unsorted array instead of printing what would be the sorted array! I don't really know how to thank you guys, but maybe I'll post what I did and make that as my answer when I get back from work. Thank you very much everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think the main bug, it was the functions with high.copyTo(...) and low.copyTo(...) with wrong indexing

Here the complete source code (tested):

```
public static int[] MergeSort(int[] array)
{
  if (array.Length <= 1)
  {
    return array;
  }

  Tuple<int[], int[]> p = SplitArray(array);

  int[] left = MergeSort(p.Item1);
  int[] right = MergeSort(p.Item2);

  return Merge(left, right);
}

public static int[] Merge(int[] low, int[] high)
{
  int[] middle = new int[low.Length + high.Length];
  int count = 0;
  foreach (int item in low)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("low: " + item + ',');
  }
  foreach (int item in high)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("high: " + item + ',');
  }
  int low_index = 0;
  int high_index = 0;
  while (low_index < low.Length && high_index < high.Length)
  {
    if (low[low_index] < high[high_index])
    {
      middle[count] = low[low_index];
      low_index++;
      count++;
      Console.WriteLine("Low inserted.");
    }
    else
    {
      middle[count] = high[high_index];
      high_index++;
      count++;
      Console.WriteLine("High inserted.");
    }

  }
  if (low_index == low.Length)
  {
    for (; count < middle.Length; count++)
    {
      middle[count] = high[high_index];
      high_index++;
    }

    // alternate: Array.Copy(high, high_index, middle, count, middle.Length - count);
  }
  else
  {
    for (; count < middle.Length; count++)
    {
      middle[count] = low[low_index];
      low_index++;
    }
    // alternate: Array.Copy(low, low_index, middle, count, middle.Length - count);
  }

  return middle;
}

public static Tuple<int[], int[]> SplitArray(int[] k)
{
  int half = k.Length / 2;
  int[] a = new int[half];
  int[] b = new int[k.Length - half];

  int k_index = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
  {
    a[i] = k[k_index];
    k_index++;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
  {
    b[i] = k[k_index];
    k_index++;
  }

  return new Tuple<int[], int[]>(a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: Code was full of bugs, lenght of arrays did not match and you where overriding your middle array every time.

```
namespace MainClass
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] array = { 3, 5, 15, 22, 12, 15, 23 };

            int[] x = MergeSort(array);

            foreach (int i in x)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    public static int[] MergeSort(int[] array)
    {
        if (array.Length <= 1)
        {
            return array;
        }
        (int[], int[]) p = SplitArray(array);
        int[] left = MergeSort(p.Item1);
        int[] right = MergeSort(p.Item2);
        return Merge(left, right);


    }



    public static int[] Merge(int[] low, int[] high)
    {
        int[] middle = new int[(low.Length + high.Length)];
        int count = 0;
        foreach (int item in low)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("low: " + item + ',');
        }
        foreach (int item in high)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("high: " + item + ',');
        }
        int low_index = 0;
        int high_index = 0;
        while (low_index < low.Length && high_index < high.Length)
        {
            if (low[low_index] < high[high_index])
            {
                middle.SetValue(low[low_index], count);
                low_index++;
                count++;
                Console.WriteLine("Low inserted.");
            }
            else
            {
                middle.SetValue(high[high_index], count);
                high_index++;
                count++;
                Console.WriteLine("High inserted.");
            }

        }
        while (high_index < high.Length)
        {
            middle[low_index + high_index] = high[high_index++];
        }
        while (low_index < low.Length)
        {
            middle[low_index + high_index] = low[low_index++];
        }

        return middle;
    }


    public static (int[], int[]) SplitArray(int[] k)
    {
        int[] a = new int[((k.Length + 1) / 2)];
        int[] b = new int[(k.Length / 2)];

        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            a[i] = k[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
        {
            b[i] = k[i + a.Length];
        }
        return (a, b);

    }

}
```